# Covering all, but $k$ points with affine subspaces

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-fields, incidence-geometry, finite-geometry

For non-negative integer $d\le n$ and $k\le 2^n$, how many affine subspaces of co-dimension $d$ are needed to cover all, but exactly $k$ elements of the vector space ${\mathbb F}_2^n$, and what are the possible values of $k$?

I know the answer in two particular cases. The case $d=1$ is about hyperplane coverings. It is not difficult to see that in this case $k$ must be a power of $2$, and for all but $k=2^s$ elements to be covered, one needs at least $n-s$ hyperplanes.

Another situation where the answer is known to me is $k=1$: by a year 1977 result of R. Jamison, to cover all but exactly one element of ${\mathbb F}_2^n$, one needs at least $n+2^d-d-1$ affine co-$d$-subspaces.

What is the answer in the general case? Has it ever been studied?

Comment: What is the easy proof for d=1 and k=1? I thought you need algebraic methods to prove this. http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~z-furedi/PUBS/furedi_alon_cube-covering.pdf

Comment: @domotorp: By a straightforward induction on $p$, the subset uncovered by $p$ hyperplanes, if nonempty, is an affine subspace of codimension at most $p$. 

Comment: @domotorp: I know that paper of Alon and Furedi, but this is what I call "easy to see"! Another (an maybe, yet easier) way to get the conclusion is to observe that the complement of a union of $d$ hyperplanes is an intersection of $d$ hyperplanes, hence is given by a system of $d$ linear equations. And, I do not claim that I know a simple proof for $k=1$ and $d$ arbitrary.

Comment: @domotorp. There is an easy proof for $k=d=1$ using a variant of the proof of Chevalley-Warning. 
Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional affine space over a finite field $F$ with $q$ elements. (Here $q=2$.)  
Take the product $P$ of all equations of the involved affine hyperplanes. Then $\sum_{x\in V}P(x)\neq 0$ since all terms are zero but one.
On the other hand, if $\deg(P)<n(q-1)$, the sum is zero (because the monomials of $P$ are of the form $x_1^{d_1}\dots x_n^{d_n}$ and $d_i<q-1$ for at least one $i$). So $\deg(P)\geq n(q-1)$.



Comment: @domotorp (followed). Moreover, you can cover $V$ minus one point by $n(q-1)$ hyperplanes. Just take translates of coordinates hyperplanes with equations $x_i=a$, for $1\leq i\leq n$ and $a\neq 0$.

Comment: @Ilya: You are right, it becomes hard only for R instead of F2.
@ACL: This is essentially the proof I linked to.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some partial answers to your question.

Let $A = A_1 \times \dots \times A_n \subseteq F^n$ be a finite grid. 
Alon and Furedi proved that you need at least $\sum (\# A - 1)$ hyperplanes to cover all but one points of $A$. 
If your $k$ is small enough (less than $\min \# A_i$), then you can use this bound to show that to cover all but $k$ points you need at least $\sum (\# A_i - 1) - k + 1$ hyperplanes, since by adding $k - 1$ hyperplanes you'll be covering all but one. 
This seems to be a tight bound for small enough $k$.

Now let $B = B_1 \times \dots \times B_n$ be a sub-grid of $A$, i.e., $B_i \subseteq A_i$ for all $i$. S. Ball and O. Serra have proved a theorem that they called ``[Punctured Combinatorial Nullstellensatz](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00493-009-2509-z)'' which can be used here to show the following:

The minimum number of hyperplanes you need to cover all points of $A$ except some point of $B$ is at least $\sum (\# A_i - \# B_i)$.

This can also be proved directly by induction on the degree of polynomial associated with the hyperplane cover, or on $\sum (\# A_i - \# B_i)$. And in fact, easier proofs of the punctured combinatorial nullstellensatz can be given.

This might give you better bounds for certain values of $k$. Especially when the $k$ points are arranged *nicely*.

Some other results in this general direction that can be useful are, [Covering all points except one](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10801-009-0204-1), [How many $s$-subspaces must miss a point set in $PG(d , q)$](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00022-006-1889-0).
The latter could probably give you the best possible results for the general case of covering all points but some by affine subspaces.